# Add class to only one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have this function that adds or removes the navIsVisible class to a menu item. It allows a dropdown to appear. However, when I add two of those menu items and click one of them, the dropdown for both appears. I know this is because the two items share the same class and are identical, but how can I work around that without using ID's, because I'm trying to make the menu generation data-driven. Or how can I work around this in general? How can I get this function to only affect the trigger that I am clicking?

Toggle function:

```
function toggleNav(){
        var navIsVisible = ( !$('.cd-dropdown').hasClass('dropdown-is-active') ) ? true : false;
        $('.cd-dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);
        $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);
        if( !navIsVisible ) {
            $('.cd-dropdown').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
                $('.has-children ul').addClass('is-hidden');
                $('.move-out').removeClass('move-out');
                $('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
            }); 
        }
    }
```

Class being added:

```
$('.cd-dropdown-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        toggleNav();
    });
```

I would really appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `this`. Something like `toggleNav( this );` and  `this.toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the click target as an argument to your `toggleNav` function and toggle that instead of finding all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

when you capture the click, pass on the `currentTarget` to your toggleNav function and use that to determine which `div` to target:

```
$('.cd-dropdown-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleNav(event.currentTarget);
});
```

Comment: What about passing `this`?

Comment: same result! could even pass it as a jQuery object $(this) or $(event.currentTarget) so that you can use it straight away in the Navfunction

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.first()` jQuery filter to your selector. More info at https://api.jquery.com/first/

```
$('.cd-dropdown').first().toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);
```

Comment: This isn't going to work.  If the user clicks on the dropdown that comes second in the markup, its going to apply the class change to the first.